# NoInitialContextException when running JMS test in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jms

In my project 2 components interact via JMS. We are trying to automate this interaction using JMeter. Both the components have provided below details:

- **JNDI Name value** is  **Initial context factory**
- **Connection URL (T3 URL)** value is **Provider URL**,
- **Connection factory JNDI Name** value is **Connection Factory**,
- **Destination JNDI Name** value is **Destination**

I have entered these values respectively into "JMS Publisher" and "JMS Subscriber" of JMeter under Test Plan-Thread Group.
On running it, error message is appearing. How to resolve this error?

```
javax.naming.NamingException: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: eis.jms.WLSConnectionFactoryJNDIXA [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: eis.jms.WLSConnectionFactoryJNDIXA]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.client.InitialContextFactory.lookupContext(InitialContextFactory.java:68) ~[ApacheJMeter_jms-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.client.InitialContextFactory.getContext(InitialContextFactory.java:155) ~[ApacheJMeter_jms-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.client.ReceiveSubscriber.<init>(ReceiveSubscriber.java:230) ~[ApacheJMeter_jms-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.client.ReceiveSubscriber.<init>(ReceiveSubscriber.java:114) ~[ApacheJMeter_jms-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.SubscriberSampler.initReceiveClient(SubscriberSampler.java:131) ~[ApacheJMeter_jms-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.SubscriberSampler.initClient(SubscriberSampler.java:345) [ApacheJMeter_jms-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.SubscriberSampler.threadStarted(SubscriberSampler.java:337) [ApacheJMeter_jms-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:802) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:1029) [jorphan.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:1012) [jorphan.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:770) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:758) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:264) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_371]
2023-12-21 17:36:59,204 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.SubscriberSampler: Could not initialise client
javax.naming.NamingException: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: eis.jms.WLSConnectionFactoryJNDIXA [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: eis.jms.WLSConnectionFactoryJNDIXA]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.client.InitialContextFactory.lookupContext(InitialContextFactory.java:68) ~[ApacheJMeter_jms-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.client.InitialContextFactory.getContext(InitialContextFactory.java:155) ~[ApacheJMeter_jms-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.client.ReceiveSubscriber.<init>(ReceiveSubscriber.java:230) ~[ApacheJMeter_jms-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.client.ReceiveSubscriber.<init>(ReceiveSubscriber.java:114) ~[ApacheJMeter_jms-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.SubscriberSampler.initReceiveClient(SubscriberSampler.java:131) ~[ApacheJMeter_jms-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.SubscriberSampler.initClient(SubscriberSampler.java:345) [ApacheJMeter_jms-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.SubscriberSampler.handleErrorAndAddTemporize(SubscriberSampler.java:238) [ApacheJMeter_jms-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.SubscriberSampler.sample(SubscriberSampler.java:157) [ApacheJMeter_jms-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.BaseJMSSampler.sample(BaseJMSSampler.java:98) [ApacheJMeter_jms-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_371]
2023-12-21 17:36:59,716 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2023-12-21 17:36:59,716 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2023-12-21 17:36:59,716 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2023-12-21 17:36:59,716 INFO o.a.j.p.j.c.InitialContextFactory: InitialContextFactory.close() called and Context instances cleaned up
2023-12-21 17:36:59,717 INFO o.a.j.p.j.c.InitialContextFactory: InitialContextFactory.close() called and Context instances cleaned up
2023-12-21 17:36:59,717 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need [WebLogic JMS Thin Client](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24378/jms_thin_client.htm#SACLT145), not Active MQ. Download the .jar files, drop them to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath), restart JMeter and at least this error should go away.

We cannot comment anything regarding JMeter JMS components configuration as we don't know the details of the MQ system you're trying to interact with.

Configuration parameters you can see in [Developing a Thin Client](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24378/thinclient.htm#SACLT137) article, there you can also find code snippets which could be used in [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) in case JMeter built-in JMS components are not suitable for Weblogic JMS.

You can also find [Weblogic JMS Test plan using Apache JMETER](https://weblogic-wonders.com/jms-test-plan-using-jmeter/) article useful. Here is a snapshot just in case:

[image]

Comment: U have suggested for Point to Point. But I have to provide the parameters of both the components right? This is how web logic is developed by development team. I need to go for publisher n subscriber mode right?